# Delphi: Proper time to subclass, and restore, a control?

Tags: delphi, themes, subclass, subclassing

What is the correct place/time to start subclassing a control?

What is the proper time to restore the original window proc?

Right now i subclass during form **creation**:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   FOldPanel1WindowProc := Panel1.WindowProc;
   Panel1.WindowProc := Panel1WindowProc;
end;
```

and i restore the subclassing during form **destruction**:

```
procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Panel1.WindowProc := FOldPanel1WindowProc;
end;
```

This works fine, as long as i don't use [ThemeManager](http://www.soft-gems.net/ThemeManager.php), which subclasses controls itself. As soon as a try to subclass a control that ThemeManager also sub-classes, i get very nasty errors.

i assume it's becuase i should not start the subclass during **Create** and restore it during **Destroy**. So what is the properly documented time to subclass and unsubclass a control in Delphi?

Comment: Try looking in the source to ThemeManager to see when it does the subclassing.

Comment: Sucky thing is that it puts forms on a delay list, because the underlying window handle isn't created during object construction (like with .NET controls that wrap Win32 controls)

Comment: could you hack into the same delay list?

Comment: i could hack a lot of things. i was hoping for the proper way of doing things, rather than trying something that doesn't seem to crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear from your question but I assume you get the errors when you're trying to restore the old window procedure in the form's OnDestroy event handler.

ThemeManager reverts its subclassing when processing `WM_DESTROY` for a control. Therefore you probably have to do the same: watch for `WM_DESTROY` in your new window procedure and revert your subclassing first, then call the old window procedure (and let ThemeManager do the same thing).

I haven't tested this but I think it should work.

Comment: You are right. More investigation shows that it *is* an ordering issue. Order of events now: 1. FormCreate (my sublcass)  2. ThemeManager subclass  3. FormDestroy (my unsubclass) 4. ThemeManager unsubclass. Since my subclass happens before ThemeManager's i need to unsubclass after; or i need to make ThemeManager subclass before my FormCreate.

Comment: Your solution worked. Having the sub-class handle the WM_DESTROY, and restore the original sub-class at that time fixes an error. 

i also found some undocumented methods in the TThemeManager (RegisterListener, UnregisterListener), which basically give you a WindowProc hook - just like a subclass.

Marked as answer.